# Rails CarrierWave: Uploaded file is not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a form that I create a Project in. A Project may have many Attachments.
An Attachment has a DocumentUploader mounted. 
But when I submit the form, the uploaded file is not attached to the Attachment i create. Any idea what might be wrong? I'm able to add documents to attachments when I'm testing from console.

**the form**

```
 66   .field
 67     = f.label :attachment, 'Velg vedlegg'
 68     = file_field_tag "attachments[]", type: :file, multiple: true
```

**controller**

```
 53       if @project.update(project_params)
 54
 55         if params[:attachments]
 56           params[:attachments].each do |attachment|
 57             a = @project.attachments.create!(document: attachment)
 58             Rails.logger.debug "attachment as seen from the params hash: #{attachment}"
 59             Rails.logger.debug "attachment.document is #{a.document.inspect}"
 60             Rails.logger.debug "URL is nil #{a.document.url == nil}"
```

**from the logs**

```
web.1  | Processing by Customers::ProjectsController#update as HTML
web.1  | Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XX=", 
         "project"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", 
         "attachments"=>["Screen Shot 2014-04-13 at 21.18.34.png"],

web.1  | attachment as seen from the params hash: Screen Shot 2014-04-13 at 21.18.34.png
web.1  | attachment.document is #<DocumentUploader:0x007fad727003d8 
         @model=#<Attachment id: 17, document: nil, project_id: 4, 
         created_at: "2014-08-27 11:42:00", updated_at: "2014-08-27 11:42:00">,          
         @mounted_as=:document, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007fad761cef28 
         @uploader=#<DocumentUploader:0x007fad727003d8 ...>>>
web.1  | URL is nil true
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :attachments
```

**attachment.rb**

```
1 class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
2   mount_uploader :document, DocumentUploader
3 end
```

**testing with Better Errors**

```
>> a
=> #<Attachment id: 21, document: nil, project_id: 4, created_at: "2014-08-27 12:57:42", updated_at: "2014-08-27 12:57:42">
>> a.document = attachment
=> "400.png"
>> a.save
=> true
>> a
=> #<Attachment id: 21, document: nil, project_id: 4, created_at: "2014-08-27 12:57:42", updated_at: "2014-08-27 12:58:10">
>> a.document.url
=> nil
```

Comment: If you inspect the attachment over the document, do you see the document property populated? I wonder if it's because you're looking at the document's model instance variable vs the document it self.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please try to rephrase? :)

Comment: Sure. If you log `Rails.logger.debug ">>>>>>>>> #{a.inspect}"` do you see the document field populated with a filename?

Comment: web.1  | >>>>>>>>> #<Attachment id: 19, document: nil, project_id: 4

Comment: I raised an exception on line 54 and tried to save it manually from the console I got from Better Errors (https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) Please see what I did in my post.

Comment: I think something might be wrong with how you're passing data through. Here's the output from logging params[:media_file] and params[:media_file].inspect a file_field tag in an app i have. http://pastie.org/9506804 I am not getting a string. Is your form_for set to multipart true?

Comment: Interesting enough though, i can create and save the attachment field with a string path. `PostMedia.create media_file: "test.png"` does have the media_file field set to the path.

Comment: That's it! I had initialized the form wrong! :-|  `== form_for [@customer, @project], multipart: true do |f|`  should have been `==form_for [@customer, @project], :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f|`  Thanks for helping out!! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have multipart set to true in a form that has any file attachments. Example:

```
= form_for [@post], html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  .field
    = f.text_field :title
  .field
    = f.file_field :image_attachment
```